# Can you change SFMC Subscriber Key w/o SF Support?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, subscriber-key, etl

Do you need SFMC Support to change the current subscriber id field from one existing field to another, no data migration or changes. And if so, is this still considered a rekey?

**Context:**
We are currently using the SF Contact ID as Subscriber Key, but wish to change to a custom object field. We are not using the standard Salesforce sync, my team built a data service that sends a flat-file to MC FTP, which is then added to data extension.

Thanks to all who view or respond!

Answer (score 2):

My Salesforce Marketing Cloud AE has confirmed this is a Subscriber Rekey that only they can fulfill.

Thanks to all who viewed and considered my question!